# Finding closest match for latitude and longitude with hibernate

Tags: java, hql, latitude-longitude

Let's say I get the user to pick long and lat on map. I have database with following columns:

```
zip
state
latitude
longitude
city
full_state
```

How do I retrieve the closest match for long and lat with hibernate HQL query?

Comment: 'closed match' vs 'without calculating the distance' - these two don't seem to be compatible.

Comment: Maybe it's just me, but how can I fulfill the requirement for 'closest match' (the smallest distance, right?) without calculating the distance? BTW, I know this doesn't help you much, so let's wait for some clever guys to provide you with a query.

Comment: There is no easy way to do this without special software to handle the GIS searches. See Augusto's answer below. You could try http://www.hibernatespatial.org/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One simple thing that you could do, is write your query so that you search for anything within a set range of from a given latitude and longitude.  For example you could search for anything where:

latitude<(latitude+<your boundary>) 
and latitude>(latitude-<your boundary>) 
and longitude<(longitude+<your boundary>) 
and longitude>(longitude-<your boundary>)

I think 1 degree of latitude or longitude is about about 69.11 miles. so to find anything within 50 miles set your boundary to be around 0.8

Comment: that is how I would look into doing it.  You would not really need to worry about a point object.  What you could do is set some boundry, then in your search search for anything where the latitude<(latitude+<your boundry>) and latitude>(latitude-<your boundry>) and longitude<(longitude+<your boundry>) and longitude>(longitude-<your boundry>)

Comment: That should give you anything within a radios of the boundary that you entered.  For example, 1 degree or latitude or longitude is about about 69.11 miles.  so to find anything within 50 miles set your boundary to be around 0.8 or around there.

Comment: It looks like it should work.  Did you try a couple of test cases to make sure that it does?

Comment: all you would have to do is add another couple of cases.  so for the latitude look for anything where the (lat+minBoundary)>(lat+maxBoundaryoundary) and (lat-maxBoundary)>(lat-MaxBoundary)

Comment: I think you may be able to shorten it and just use the (lat+minBoundary) cases that I described above.  just add the ones for longitude.  I am pretty sure that that is all that is needed.  Just try it to make sure that it works.

Comment: turn on debugging so you can see the query that is used then try running it manually.

Comment: This is great. I have a database with about 2600 points, and I wanted to calculate the closest point for a given lat/lon. Currently, I calculated the distance to each of these (by using the haversine formula in a mysql function), but if I narrow it down the way John Kane did, it should take up a lot less resources to calculate out in a 70 mile radius. Fantastic!

Answer (score 2):

This answer wont answer your question specifically, but there are special database engines to handle geographical data, because otherwise, as you mentioned, you need to go through all you data and calculate the distance for every user request.

I've done something like that before using [oracle spatial](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oracle_Spatial)... reading that wiki page, I found that there's an extension for Postgres called [PostGis](http://postgis.refractions.net/) which also allows spatial queries.

I know that it's not hibernate, but I strongly suggest you to check those engines.

Answer (score 0):

why don't use simply type Point or Geom in hibernate? with those types you can execute all query you want with hql and POSTGIS? you can create point simply like this :

ST_POINTFROMTEXT('POINT(LONGITUDE LATITUDE)')

????